# GROUP_BY show only first occurrence if value equals

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table called questions with the following row:

```
questions.id | questions.target_username
   1         | every.one
   2         | every.one
```

I have also the answers table with the following rows:

```
answers.id | answers.username       
   1       | guy
   1       | maricela 
   2       | mikha
```

As you can see, the same question id could have answers from different users.
I want to select only rows if:

a) question has answers that don't include (mikha) as answers.username and in this case display the question id once only

b) question has the answer username (mikha) as answers.username.

I use the following query:

```
SELECT questions.id, answers.username
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers ON ( questions.id = answers.id ) 
WHERE questions.target_username =  'every.one'
AND (
answers.username IS NOT NULL 
OR answers.username =  'mikha'
)
GROUP BY questions.id, answers.username
```

Result I expect:

```
questions.id | answers.usernme
   1         |  
   2         | mikha
```

What I actually get:

```
questions.id | answers.usernme
   1         | guy
   1         | maricela  
   2         | mikha
```

Thanks in advance
Regards
Micahel

Comment: What's the point of `answers.username IS NOT NULL OR answers.username =  'mikha'` The first condition contains the second one, doesn't it?
Also, why are you expectiong result with an empty row where question.id equals 1? You don't have such records in rows, which you showed us.

Comment: Yes. I know the `answers.username IS NOT NULL` conflicts with the 2nd and is meaningless. that's what i can't accomplish. I need to seleect questions that have `answers.username = 'mikha'` or questions that have answers that don't include 'mikha' but in the case there are answers that don't have 'mikha'...limit only 1 result and skip to the next question id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to move the `answers.username = 'mikha'` condition to the on clause, at which point you can even remove the redundant where conditions.

```sql
SELECT questions.id, answers.username
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers ON(questions.id = answers.id AND answers.username = 'mikha')
WHERE questions.target_username = 'every.one'
GROUP BY questions.id, answers.username;
```

Edit:
I'm not sure if this is a requirement or not, but if you want to omit questions that have not had anyone answer them yet, the following is what you would want:

```sql
SELECT questions.id, answers.username
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers ON(questions.id = answers.id AND answers.username = 'mikha')
LEFT JOIN answers others ON(questions.id = others.id AND others.username <> 'mikha')
WHERE questions.target_username = 'every.one'
AND (
    (
        answers.id IS NOT NULL
        AND others.id IS NULL
    )
    OR (
        answers.id IS NULL
        AND others.id IS NOT NULL
    )
)
GROUP BY questions.id, answers.username;
```

Edit 2: Here's what I have in my test tables, and the results from query #2:

```
SELECT * FROM questions;
+----+-----------------+
| id | target_username |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | every.one       |
|  2 | every.one       |
|  3 | every.one       |
|  4 | every.one       |
+----+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM answers;
+-----+----+----------+
| ida | id | username |
+-----+----+----------+
|   1 |  1 | guy      |
|   2 |  1 | maricela |
|   3 |  2 | mikha    |
+-----+----+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

(Run query #2 above)
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | NULL     |
|  2 | mikha    |
+----+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Edit 3: Here are updated table data and an updated query that complies with the criteria you added in the comments:

```
SELECT * FROM questions;
+----+-----------------+
| id | target_username |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | every.one       |
|  2 | every.one       |
|  3 | every.one       |
|  4 | every.one       |
+----+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM answers;
+-----+----+----------+
| ida | id | username |
+-----+----+----------+
|   1 |  1 | guy      |
|   2 |  1 | maricela |
|   3 |  2 | mikha    |
|   7 |  4 | guy      |
|   8 |  4 | mikha    |
+-----+----+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

New query:

```sql
SELECT questions.id, answers.username
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers ON(questions.id = answers.id AND answers.username = 'mikha')
LEFT JOIN answers others ON(questions.id = others.id AND others.username <> 'mikha')
WHERE questions.target_username = 'every.one'
AND (
    answers.username = 'mikha'
    OR (
        answers.id IS NULL
        AND others.id IS NOT NULL
    )
)
GROUP BY questions.id, answers.username;
```

Result:

```
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | NULL     |
|  2 | mikha    |
|  4 | mikha    |
+----+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Still this doesn't answer my question. I want to select questions where answer is not null and at the same time doesn't contain "mikha" as an `answers.username` and display only 1 result. In this case,  it displays all the results available. It displays "guy" and "maricela". I want to display only 1 and then skip to the next question id

Comment: Are you sure the second one doesn't?  It gives me your "expected" results.

Comment: I added my test data and results to the answer, @Michael

Comment: Justm tried it but there are questions that have answers by both "mikha" and others. When I tested, these aren't included. How can I inlcude those as well?? thanks :)

Comment: This one is PERFECT! Thanks Starson and all others for your wonderful effort :) really appreciate it

Comment: Could I ask you...what does the `answers.id IS NULL
AND others.id IS NOT NULL` part mean? It's working well but I can't figure out how it works in limiting the restults to 1 in case question doesn't have an answer by "mikha". It's giving the results I need but just can't understand how it works. Thanks :)

Comment: I just tried to remove `answers.id IS NULL` and it's still giving the same result..that's why i'm trying to understand how the query works

Comment: Great!  Please accept this as the answer :)  That block essentially says "If there were no answers by 'mikha', but there were answers by others" and the line above that that block essentially says "If there was an answer by you".  Put them together, along with the conditions in the ON clauses, and you get the results you are looking for.

Comment: But isn't the 2nd condition supposed when no answer by mikha, give all the answers by the others in different rows? how you make it give only the row once?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20778/discussion-between-starson-hochschild-and-michael-samuel)

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter you answers table ,

Change the answer.Id to question.Id and add answer.Id as a primary key...

In you aim is not clear as the results you expect has a row 2, mikha (your said if the username is mikha I need only question Id) ?

Comment: The problem mainly with the first case nor the second. The second will always display one row as the user can answer the question only once

Answer (score 0):

If you join to answer ids only those usernames which are 'mikha' you should get desired result. Those ids which have answers but not mikhas answer will get null value. I didn't understand where you would have needed questions table to get this information:

```
SELECT answers.id, a2.username
FROM answers
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT id, username
   FROM answers
   WHERE username = 'mikha'
) AS a2 ON a2.id = answers.id
GROUP BY answers.id
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to do this without subqueries or corelated queries? As they are a performance hit

Comment: Also I want both conditions...if mikha is who answered..or if no answer by mikha...show the question one time only. I think this needs CASE function but don't know how to approach it?

Comment: This will get all the questions which have answers but joining a2 will be successful only if mikha has answered. If mikha haven't answered it will show null. But I can show other way to do this too...

Comment: In fact, I think your problem can't be solved without subquery or correlated query

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I know how to select when mikha is the  answer

Comment: I saw you found a solution, but did you test this with your data? Because this should give the same result as you got.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this result is:

1. `answers.username IS NOT NULL OR answers.username = 'mikha'` is a poor condition. The second case, `answers.username = 'mikha'` is already a situation in which `answers.username IS NOT NULL` - so it is a meaningless second conditional.
2. The `LEFT JOIN`, when added in with this condition, is essentially just equivalent to an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: In fact i am not sure that i understood what you need. A/ and B/ are just complemetary... did i miss something?

Comment: please use \`a code here\` to format codes, this will make people read your post easier. For example: \`answers.username IS NOT NULL OR answers.username = 'mikha'\` will display: `answers.username IS NOT NULL OR answers.username = 'mikha'`

Comment: Still this doesn't answer my question. I want to select questions where answer is not null and at the same time doesn't contain "mikha" as an answers.username and display only 1 result. In this case, it displays all the results available. It displays "guy" and "maricela". I want to display only 1 and then skip to the next question id

Comment: I know that the `answers.username IS NOT NULL` is meaningless